# Selenium поиск по тексту как реализовать?

Tags: python, selenium

Пишу код для покупки на сайте, автоматизированной и столкнулся с проблемой, на разных товарах элементы разные, но мне нужно добавлять товар именно по размеру например по размеру US 11(44), но так как на разных сайтах индивидуальные элементы сделать я это не могу, и так вопрос. Возможен ли поиск по самому тексту в Selenium? К примеру

```
<label for="skuAndSize__24970758" tabindex="-1" class="css-xf3ahq">US 10 (RU 43)</label>
```

Так что бы при назначении US10, в корзину добавлялся этот размер не по классу, всем спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элемент по тексту можно найти используя поиск по `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'US 10')]")
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
То есть я не смогу кликнуть по этому элементу?

Comment: Закралась опечатка. `find_elements_by_xpath` возвращает список элементов, вам нужен один - значит используйте `find_element_by_xpath`